# How to zip files in mac without root folder

Tags: mac, terminal, zip

I used this command

```
>zip -r name.zip myfolder
```

to zip files in a folder. I want to zip all the files in `myfolder` without including `myfolder` in zip file.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I managed to overcome this problem using below command

```
>cd myfolder
>zip -r name.zip .
```

Comment: Still creates the parent folder when extracting. `A` & `B` files are within `P` folder. Zipped `P` with this command but when extract the `P.zip` -> `P/A,B`

Answer (score 2):

```
zip -jr name.zip myfolder/*
```

The -j will junk the path. I'm adding this solution because it was the top link when googling for it.